# Make all bootstrap modals draggable using Jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, modal-dialog

I have read a post regarding making Bootstrap's modals draggable which I can do by calling:

```
$(this).draggable({
    handle: ".modal-header"
});
```

Where the dialog is created on the page.

The problem is, is that I have many dialogs throughout my system and I want to make them all draggable, without having to find every dialog instance and dropping in that code snippet.

Is there a way to make all dialogs draggable by *default*?

I have tried:

```
$('.modal').on('show', function(){
  $(this).draggable({
      handle: ".modal-header"
    });
})
```

In my global script, but it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try It:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".modal").each(function(i) {
        $(this).draggable({
            handle: ".modal-header"  
        });
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

To use draggable plugin to dynamically created element use

```
(function ($) {
   $.fn.dynamicDraggable = function (opts) {
      this.live("mouseover", function() {
         if (!$(this).data("init")) {
            $(this).data("init", true).draggable(opts);
         }
      });
      return this;
   };
}(jQuery));
```

And use it as

```
$(".modal").dynamicDraggable({
     handle: ".modal-header"  
});
```

Comment: The problem is, is that the markup for the dialogs doesn't exist and are dynamically added to the DOM. On another note, is it generally better to have all dialogs that might be used on the page to be already in the DOM and hidden, not having the HTML dynamically loaded?

Comment: Unfortunately I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$('.modal').draggable({
    handle: ".modal-content"  
});
```

This will find all html elements with class 'modal' and make them draggable.

I used '.modal-content' instead of 'modal-header' because I don't want users to get stuck if they dragged the modal too far up on the screen. With '.modal-content' they can drag it back from the bottom of the modal.

Please note that you have to use Jquery UI for this to work.

Use document.ready() to ensure all modals are loaded before this code is applied.

If you're using AngularJS like me, and have multiple controllers and views, or not all of your modals are available in the DOM initially, then you can use ng-init on each modal div to call the function that makes them draggable.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal" ng-init="makeDraggable()">
```

Javascript:

```
$rootScope.makeDraggable = function () {
            $('.modal').draggable({
                handle: ".modal-content"
            });
            $('.modal').addClass('click');
        };
```